# Simple way to fetch data from local json in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new in flutter and I can't fetch data from local json file. I have this json files.

```
[
  {
    "facetsDistribution": {
      "authors": {
        "Carlo Collodi": 1,
        "Charles Perrault": 2     
      },      
      "language": {
        "EN": 5,
        "FR": 1
      },
      "tags": {}
    }
}
]
```

Now I want to display authors and language (key) in a ListView widget. Who can help me with simples code for this situation?

Comment: Q: Are you unable to read the file?  Q: Or have you successfully read the JSON, and now you want to render the data in a GUI?  1) **Read/Write files**: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/reading-writing-files, 2) **Display JSON**: here's one very quick'n'simple option (one option of *MANY*): https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_json_viewer/ (note: you could use this widget *instead of* a ListView widget)

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert JSON data into Dart object files which then you can display in your Flutter UI.

For starters you can do this by manually creating factory constructors for your classes as shown below:

```
class FacetsDistribution {
  final Authors authors;
  final Language language;

  FacetsDistribution({
    required this.authors,
    required this.language,
  });

  factory FacetsDistribution.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) =>
      FacetsDistribution(
        authors:
            Authors.fromJson(parsedJson['authors'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
        language:
            Language.fromJson(parsedJson['language'] as Map<String, dynamic>),
      );
}

class Authors {
  final String value1;
  final String value2;

  Authors({
    required this.value1,
    required this.value2,
  });

  factory Authors.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) => Authors(
        value1: parsedJson['Carlo Collodi'] as String,
        value2: parsedJson['Charles Perrault'] as String,
      );
}

class Language {
  final String value1;
  final String value2;

  Language({
    required this.value1,
    required this.value2,
  });

  factory Language.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) => Language(
        value1: parsedJson['EN'] as String,
        value2: parsedJson['FR'] as String,
      );
}
```

factory className.fromJson constructors which I defined in every class serve the purpose of parsing json data we receive (having the structure of Map<String, dynamic>) and convert them into dart objects.

In those constructors we provide our key value `value1: parsedJson['EN']` as an example and specify the datatype into which we want the data to be parsed `as String` at the end of line.

You also can automate all this using the [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) package. But I would recommend knowing how it works by doing it manually and then automating it later on.